# How to manage validations of many form fields in react?

Tags: reactjs, validation

### How to manage a large number of form field validations in React

I have 50 form fields in my application. How to manage validations for such a large number of fields. Is it better to use controlled components (using onChange) or Uncontrolled components?

I also need to show Customized error messages. For now, I am using constraint  validation API.

Comment: Maybe this could help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296668/reactjs-form-input-validation/41297611#41297611)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the validation type ...
If you just need to check mandatory fields, just use the required attribute of input. 
If you want to validate a certain string pattern, use the HTML5 attibute `pattern`.

Here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Formulaires/Validation_donnees_formulaire) to help you