# TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateFields' of undefined ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, antd

I have two pages *addressForm.js* and *index.js*. In *addressForm.js* page the code for Form is written. Sample code shown below.

```
<Col >
                    <div style={{'height': '45px','display':'flex'}}> 
                    <label style={{'color': '#f5222d', 'paddingTop': '10px','fontFamily': 'SimSun'}}>*</label>&nbsp;
                    <label style={{'width':'74px','paddingTop':'8px'}}>Customer Name:</label>                       
                        <FormItem >
                        {getFieldDecorator('Name', {
                        initialValue: '',
                        rules: [{
                            required: true, 
                            message: (
                              <Tooltip
                                visible={true} placement="topRight"
                                title="Please Input Customer Name"
                              />
                            ),
                        }],
                        })(
                        <Input placeholder="Customer Name" style={{'width':'164px'}} onChange={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();                                   
                            this.handleChange(0,e, 'Name')}}/>
                        )}                    
                    </FormItem>
                    </div>
                    </Col>
```

In the *index.js* page fuctions for the form is written (What to happen when the **Submit** button is clicked). Sample Code:

```
handleOk = () => {
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          /* Code.......*/
 }
    });
    }
```

The problem is that the validation is not working (ie.,validation checking is not done and I am getting this error).

Shall I import anything in index.js page to avoid the error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateFields' of undefined ReactJS

Comment: this.props.form is undefined. Can you check this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296668/reactjs-form-input-validation

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this issue by trying this code:

```
class Devices extends React.Component {
   .................
}

Devices = Form.create({})(Devices);
export default Devices;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in your props is not being passed in or defined correctly, which is giving the TypeError. It looks like you might need to pass in props explicitly into your handleOk function - its hard to tell though with the snippets provided.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.create(options)), `form` should be decorated by `Form.create`.

> If the form has been decorated by Form.create then it has this.props.form property.

```
class CustomizedForm extends React.Component {}

CustomizedForm = Form.create({})(CustomizedForm);
```