# How to validate input before submitting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hooks, form-submit

I want to validate input before submitting. But something went wrong, every time submit() run :((

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
const [error, setError] = React.useState("");
const validate = () => {
  value.length>5?setError("Some errors"):setError("");
}
const submit = () => {do something...}
...
<input onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />

<Button  onClick={() => {
  validate();
  if(!error.length) submit()
}> Submit </Button>
```

Comment: setError is async and the new value of error will not be updated until rerender. Maybe change validate to return a string and not update the state value, you can then setError in the button onClick as well as check it in the if statement.

Comment: How can i pass this ?

Comment: setError is not async. It's synchronous but the value of the original `error` variable does not change as it's already been assigned. It takes a new re-render (calling the component function again) to reassign the variable again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs - Form input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296668/reactjs-form-input-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `error` variable will only contain the new value in the next render of the component. This is due to the way `useState`, or rather Hooks in general work.

Instead, you'll have to return whether or not the result is valid in the validate function.

```
const validate = () => {
  value.length>5?setError("Some errors"):setError("");
  return value.length <= 5;
}

<Button  onClick={() => {
  const isValid = validate();
  if(isValid) submit()
}> Submit </Button>
```