# Form validation in Reactjs onchange input fields

Tags: html, reactjs, css-selectors

Hello I am new learner of react.
anybody please help me in form validation on(onchange) input Fields

> ```
> <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="Username">
>         <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
>         <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Lastname"  name='username' value={Validation} onChange={textchange}/>
>       </Form.Group>
>       <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
>         <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
>         <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email"  name='email' value={Validation.email}  onChange={emailchange}/>
>         <Form.Text className="text-muted">
>           We'll never share your email with anyone else.
>         </Form.Text>
>       </Form.Group>
>       <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
>         <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
>         <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password"  name='password' autoComplete="on"  onChange={passchange}
> ```
>
> value={Validation.password}/>
> </Form.Group>
> <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
> <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
> </Form.Group>
>
> Submit

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: sir actually i have done only html code i dont know how to validate forms in react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add validation to the form in my React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296668/how-do-i-add-validation-to-the-form-in-my-react-component)

Answer (score 1):

For forms in React, you can use the `formik` package for react as it helps in validation and forms in general.

For forms you can either use `useRef` if you don't care for your component to re-render, or one of `useState` and `useReducer`.

Generally having too many states in your component (or in a form like this) is not good practice.

You can use `useReducer` as it helps manage your logic for the `onChange` property of your entire form in one place.

Generally the `onChange` property returns an `event` and the value in your field can be accessed this way:

```
onChange={event=>{setValue(event.target.value)}}
```

or using functions like you are:

```
function handleChange (event) {
setValue(event.target.value);
}
...
<input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
```

and for validation you can check before setting your state of variable depending on the conditions you need to add.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/).
It's the best library to manage forms in react.